# Convert given String to Json Object Javascript

Tags: javascript, json, string

I have a String like this :

```
var str = [sa_user{username=pankaj123, userType=dataentry}, sa_user{username=data, userType=dataentry}, sa_user{username=PANKAJ, userType=parcel}, sa_user{username=davender, userType=parcel}, sa_user{username=delhiparcel, userType=dataentry}, sa_user{username=devender, userType=dataentry}, sa_user{username=amit123, userType=dataentry}, sa_user{username=sanjay, userType=dataentry}, sa_user{username=MUKESH, userType=dataentry}, sa_user{username=test, userType=dataentry}, sa_user{username=vijaykumar, userType=dataentry}, sa_user{username=puran123, userType=dataentry}, sa_user{username=sanjaykumar, userType=dataentry}, sa_user{username=nelsonanthony, userType=dataentry}, sa_user{username=ishan, userType=dataentry}, sa_user{username=manoj, userType=parcel}, sa_user{username=ranjeet, userType=dataentry}, sa_user{username=DEEPAK, userType=dataentry}, sa_user{username=ASHISH, userType=dataentry}, sa_user{username=arjun, userType=dataentry}]
```

I want to convert the given into JSon Object or any other data-type to access every Object variables `username` and `usertype`.

Since, the String is not in the valid form to convert into JSon Object, then how can I access the variables?

Comment: You don't have a string. Should what is being assigned to `str` be enclosed in quotes?

Comment: I've got this String from server, not initialized it here, this is just an example...@Graham

Comment: convert to `json` string at server, can't you convert to json string using `JavaScriptSerializer` (in .netframework if you are using that) before sending to client ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to parse the string, convert it to a valid json string and then in javascript you can do something like this to get the object:

```
var myJsonString = ""; // your json string
var obj = JSON.parse(myJsonString);
```

**EDIT:**
Just put together a jsfiddle with a solution, it could be better, but it gets the job done for your specific case.

http://jsfiddle.net/8B7wu/1/

Comment: Let me get a jsfiddle with the answer.

Comment: @AnkitLamba just edited the answer with a solution for your specific case. Please Review it.

Answer (score 1):

your json string should look like this to parse.

```
var strJson = "[
                   {'username':'pankaj123', 'userType':'dataentry'}, 
                   {'username':'data', 'userType':'dataentry'}, 
                   {'username':'PANKAJ', userType':parcel'}, 
                   ....
               ]";
```

now solve what to do with your current string to make it like this.